# Error -[Cannot read property 'style' of null]

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, community, visualforce-component, aura

> Error ID: -270960303 This page has an error. You might just need to
>   refresh it. Error in $A.getCallback() [Cannot read property 'style' of
>   null] Failing descriptor: {c:CommunityBreakingNews}

[image]

**Controller:**

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        //var lWidth = window.innerWidth ;
        var lWidth = 400;
        window.setInterval($A.getCallback(function() { 
            helper.handleScroll(component, event,lWidth);
        } ), 20);
    }
})
```

**Helper:**

```
({
    handleScroll: function(component, event,lWidth) {
        var changeposition = component.get("v.scrollInterval");
        var floatElement = document.getElementById('toScroll');   
        if(changeposition < lWidth){
            floatElement.style.left = changeposition+'px';
            changeposition = changeposition + 1;
            component.set("v.scrollInterval",changeposition);
        }
        else{
            component.set("v.scrollInterval",0);
            floatElement.style.left = "0px";
            changeposition = component.get("v.scrollInterval");
        }
    }
})
```

**Style:**

```
.THIS#scrollDIV{
    border: 5px solid;
    border-radius: 6px;
    background: beige;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 2px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your question has no actual question written in it, I'll take a guess at what you're asking for help with here.

Your helper JS is looking for an element with an `id` of `toScroll`

```
var floatElement = document.getElementById('toScroll');   
    if(changeposition < lWidth){
        floatElement.style.left = changeposition+'px';
```

However, based on your CSS, the `id` of that element is `scrollDIV`

Because `floatElement` is null, the above error is produced when you try to access `style` on it.

If you correct the `Id` of the element, your code may work correctly.

Comment: Using `document.getElementById` in any lightning component is probably still a bad idea though.

Answer (score 1):

With locker service, you should not use the getElementById() method from the controller or helper. you should only do so from a custom renderer when the DOM is in the same namespace.

feel free to check [DOM Access Containment](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/security_dom.htm) for accessing elements in your component.

> **Valid DOM Access**
>
> The following methods are valid DOM access because the elements are
>   created by c:domLocker.
>
> - cmp.getElements()
>
> *Returns the elements in the DOM rendered by the component.*
>
> - cmp.find()
>
> *Returns the div and button components, identified by their aura:id
>   attributes.*
>
> - cmp.find("div1").getElement()
>
> *Returns the DOM element for the div as c:domLocker created the div.*
>
> - event.getSource().get("v.name")
>
> *Returns the name of the button that dispatched the event; in this
>   case, myButton.*

Example console output:
[image]